# Javascript show variable every 50 ms

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I want to make a little 'loading...' widget for my website, using javascript.

```
var percent=0;  
var message="Loading... "  
var per="%"  
function count(){  
    percent=percent+1;  
    if(percent==100){  
        alert("Loading end.")  
    }else{  
        setTimeout("count",50)  
        document.write(message)  
        document.write(percent)  
        document.write(per)  
    }
```

But it isn't running. I think I've got some mistake (or maybe totally wrong). How can I do this? I want to update the shown message every 50ms.

Comment: Is that your actual code or did you try to retype it for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with interval and clear it when progress is finished:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>testing</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="progress">MSG</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var percent = 0;
            var message = "Loading... ";
            var per = "%";
            var dom = document.getElementById('progress');
            var iv = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(message);
                dom.innerHTML = ((percent++) + per +' '+ message);
                if(percent === 100){
                    console.log("Loading end.");
                    clearInterval(iv);
                    return false;
                }
            }, 50);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is brilliant! This can run (mine cannot)

Answer (score 0):

try

> setInterval(count,50);

instead of setTimeOut("count",50)

Answer (score 0):

You want to set an interval which runs every x milliseconds, passing in an anonymous function to call the function to call

```
var percent=0;  
var message="Loading... "  
var per="%"  
function count(){  
    percent=percent+1;  
    if(percent==100){  
        alert("Loading end.")  
    }else{  
        setInterval(function() { count() },50)  
        document.write(message)  
        document.write(percent)  
        document.write(per)  
    }
} <--- you were also missing this ending brace
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, as it is more simple & I can understand it better.

Comment: Always starting a new interval is totally not the sense of setInterval(). There is also no clearing happening ever here. This example works better with setTimeout(). See @Biby Augustine answer.

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
var percent = 0;
var message = "Loading... ";
var per = "%";

$(document).ready(function () {
    count();
});

function count() {
    percent = percent + 1;
    if (percent == 100) {
        alert("Loading end.");
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            count();
        }, 50);
        document.write(message);
        document.write(percent);
        document.write(per);
    }
}
```

see this fiddle for more http://jsfiddle.net/8nhmU/19/

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bn39/1/)

HTML:

```
<span id="loading"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
var percent = 0;
var message = "Loading...";
var per = "%";
var element = document.getElementById('loading');

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    element.innerHTML = message + percent + per;
    percent += 1;
    if(percent > 100) {
        clearInterval(interval)
    };
}, 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example is missing a great deal of semi-colons *and* the ending curly-bracket, but that's not the end-issue.

The "problem" with your call to `setTimeout` is that the first argument must be an actual function, not a string. If you remove the quotes around the call, it will work.

Here is a copy of your code, re-formatted:

```
var percent=0;  
var message="Loading... ";
var per="%";

function count() {
    percent++;

    if (percent == 100) {
        alert("Loading end.");
    } else {
        setTimeout(count, 50);
        document.write(message);
        document.write(percent);
        document.write(per);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way. You should call the setInterval method when window loads. And when loading is completed, you should stop interval by clearing it using its ID.

```
var countId;
window.onload = function(){
    countId=setInterval(count,50);
}

function count(){
    if(per=99){
      clearInterval(countId);
    }
    per++;
    //show your message
}
```